# How to change contents of div in .cshtml without reloading whole page in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to change contents of div in .cshtml without reloading whole page in ASP.NET MVC 5

```
<div class="status-Container" style="display:none">
<div class="status-block">
@if (Model.Dropdownlist.selectedvalue = 1)
{
<span class="status-title"> Consultations : </span>
}
else
{ 
<span class="status-title"> Sheduled : </span>
}
</div>
</div>
```

First time only debug comes. not debug the page further.. it is not reload again.

Comment: I think you need to spend some more time with the tutorials at http://asp.net/mvc. Razor (CSHTML) is processed server-side, while the user will select a value in the drop-down client-side, long after the CSHTML has been processed. If you need to change the HTML client-side, without reloading the page, you must use AJAX.

Comment: yes Mr. Chris Pratt  I am new to MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ajax and make call to the controller and get the data you wanted to change. Sample code below.

```
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/FunName', //@Url.Action("FunName","ControllerName")
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { selectedvalue: selectedvalue },
        success: function (data) { //Make the function to return the partial view you want which would be fetched in the data
            $('#DynamicContent').html(data); 
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Vasu if you are satisfied with the answer accept it and vote up. No need of thanks.